# Symfony2 ajax form validation render errors in twig

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

i have a form in Symfony2 which i validate with ajax. This is all working, and i get back a json with  "global" (for global errors) and "fields" (errors for each field in here) in my success statement of the ajax call:

```
{"global":[],"fields":{"fos_user_registration_form_username":"Please enter a 
username","fos_user_registration_form_email":"Please enter an 
email","fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first":"Please enter a password"}}
```

My question is: What is the best way to present these errors from "fields" in the view for each field? I rendered the view elements as the following when i validated the form without ajax:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   {{ form_label(form.xyz) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.xyz) }}
   {{ form_errors(form.xyz) }}
 </div>
```

How can i inject now the errors from the "field" list of my json object into the appropriate

```
{{ form_errors(form.xyz) }}
```

?

I would love to hear your ideas and best practices.

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You add them via Javascript/jQuery.

I've a similar situation and this is my code:

The Js code that post form data and show errors messages in case of errors.

```
$.ajax({

    url : $(this).attr('action') + ".json",
    method : 'POST',
    data : $(this).serialize(),

}).done(function(data) {

        // Code in case of success

}).fail(function(jqXHR) {

   $.each(jqXHR.responseJSON.errors.children, function(k, v) {

       errorsText = "";

       if ((v.errors) && (v.errors.length > 0)) {
           $.each(v.errors, function(n, errorText) {
               errorsText += errorText;
           });
           $('#form_'+k).tooltip('destroy');
           $('#form_'+k).tooltip({'title': errorsText});    
           $('#form_'+k).closest('div[class="form-group"]').addClass('has-error');
        } else {
           $('#form_'+k).closest('div[class="form-group has-error"]').removeClass('has-error');
           $('#form_'+k).tooltip('destroy');
      }

   });
}
```

Here is my Json in case of error. Is the standard one you get if you use FOSRestBundle

```
{
   "code":400,
   "message":"Validation Failed",
   "errors":{
      "children":{
         "name":{
            "errors":[
               "This value should not be blank."
            ]
         }
         "email":{
            "errors":[
               "This value should not be blank."
            ]
         }
         "privacy":{
            "errors":[
               "This value should not be blank."
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The HTML for my form is

```
<form id="sfForm" action="/landingbuilder/landing/test_template" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="form_name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_name" name="form[name]" required="required" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    [..]

</form>
```

If you need more details just ask

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. Was really helpful.
I got a question on my controller. I was using the FosUserBundle RegistrationController. I've overwritten it and "minimalized" the registerAction method to only render the blank registration form first. I have outsourced the logic to validate the form into another method for the ajax request. So my registerAction() creates an empty user object , that the fields are displayed and rendered.And then in the validateRegistrationAction() i create another new user object that gets validated with the form data. Is this the right way to do that ? Regards.

Comment: Well, this is not related to your first question. Please accept my response if you think is correct and post a new one.

Comment: Hi, i accepted your answer. No you are wrong, it is related. It is the controller that sends me back the json answer. Is my architecture right ?